# Three tank mixing problem, help with set up

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

So I am having trouble composing the system of ODE's that will model the following scenario.

> Three tanks, each 100 gallons, are connected to one another and we allow the solutions in each tank to flow to one another by the following directional circulation; Tank 1 (starting with 4 lbs of salt) flows to tank 2, Tank 2 (starting with 2 lbs of salt) flows to tank 3, and Tank 3 (starting as pure water), flows to tank 1.  Each flow rate is the same, 2 gallons per minute.  For any time $t$, what is the amount of salt in each tank, $y_1(t)=y_1, y_2(t)=y_2, y_3(t)=y_3$, at time $t$?

So I was thinking that the rate of change of salt in the first tank, is related by the ODE

$$y_1'=-0.02y_1+0.02y_3$$

tank 2;

$$y_2'=0.02y_1-0.02y_2$$

tank 3;

$$y_3'=0.02y_2-0.02y_3$$

This gives a matrix of coefficients

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-0.02 & 0 & 0.02 \\ 0.02 & -0.02 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.02 & -0.02 \end{pmatrix} $$

Then when I find $\det{(A-\lambda I)}=0 $, i find eigenvalues $\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2=-0.03+.01\sqrt{3}i, $ and $\lambda_3=-0.03-.01\sqrt{3}i$

Without adding more mathjax, I found that $\lambda_1$ has eigenvector $x_1=[1, 1, 1]^T$.  But then, when I try and plug $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ into $A-\lambda I$ and row reduce, i get eigenvectors equal to the zero vector.  So that can't be right, and I don't know what to do from here.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What you have given is correct. You obviously are messing up your arithmetic with the complex matrices. Maybe you should try factoring out the $.02$ from the matrix and see if that improves your arithmetic. (The eigenvalues of $cA$ are $c$ times the eigenvalues of $A$, and the eigenvectors are the same.)

Comment: It's crazy then, because I was using wolframalpha for the calculations of the determinant and row-reducing $A-\lambda I$.  I'm happy the set up is right then.  Gonna do it by hand now.

Comment: Looks like the factoring was the right call, getting rid of that 0.02 helped $rref(A-\lambda I)$ not be the identity matrix, and I can move on now.  Thanks!

Comment: The eigenvectors must be in the plane perpendicular to $(1, 1, 1)$